# How to set "active" class for first tab in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm setting up Foundation Zurb tabs.

It looks like this:

```
- @items.group_by(&:calendar).each do |calendar, items|
  %section
    - # displaying tab name, which is Calendar name
    - # displaying tab content, which is a table of Items for that Calendar
```

I want first tab to be `%section.active`, and all other tabs should be just `%section` (not active).

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add each with index if you group your initial two variables together by unsplatting them.

```
- @items.group_by(&:calendar).each_with_index do |(calendar, items), index|
  %section{:class => ("active" if index.zero?)}
```

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981019/rails-when-using-group-by-how-to-get-an-index) for more details.

Comment: That's a nice one. Like it.

Comment: Good. Glad to help. If this answers your question, please accept this answer to close the question out.